# Laravel Authentication - Email in different table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I have two tables:

persons:

```
id   name   email   phone   person_type_id
```

users

```
id   person_id  password role_id etc...
```

Could you please tell me how to make Laravel's (5.8) built in Authentication System use the **email** field from **persons** table when authenticating a user? FYI, the value of guard provider has to be **users**.

Comment: You can change the default user model in the auth config file but I still don't think it will work as it requires the email and password to be in the same model.  The only other way is to create a custom guard to override Larvels default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom user provider (which inherits from `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`) and override the `retrieveByCredentials` method.

See [Laravel Docs - The User Provider Contract](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#the-user-provider-contract)

Answer (score 3):

@Thomas's suggestion helped me to solve the problem. In case it helps anyone, here's my code:

I created CustomUserProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

class CustomUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider { 

private $method_to_email_model;

public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model, $method_to_email_model)
{

    parent::__construct($hasher, $model);

    $this->method_to_email_model = $method_to_email_model;
}

public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{

    if (empty($credentials) ||
       (count($credentials) === 1 &&
        array_key_exists('password', $credentials))) {
        return;
    }

    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) 
    {
        if (Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            continue;
        }

        if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Arrayable) {

            $query->with([$this->method_to_email_model => function($q) use($key, $value){
                $q->whereIn($key, $value);
            }]);

        } else {


            $query->with([$this->method_to_email_model => function($q) use($key, $value){
                $q->where($key, $value);
            }]);
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
 }   

}
```

Then in App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php file, inside boot function:

```
Auth::provider('custom_user_provider', function ($app, array $config) {
    return new CustomUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model'], $config['method_to_email_model']);
});
```

Inside config/auth.php

```
 'providers' => [ 
    'users' => [
        'driver'                => 'custom_user_provider',
        'model'                 => App\User::class,
        'method_to_email_model' => 'person',
    ],
  ],
```

Finally in App\User.php (User Model)

```
protected $appends = [
    'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'
 ];

public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'person_id', 'id');
}

public function getEmailAttribute()
{
    return $this->person->getAttribute('email');
}

public function getFirstNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->person->getAttribute('first_name');
}

public function getLastNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->person->getAttribute('last_name');
}
```